# Verification of understanding proving convergence of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

We have sequence of independent random variables $X_n$ that satysfies $$P(X_n=0)=\frac1n,\;P(X_n=n)=1-\frac1n.$$
I want to check convergence of this sequence in probability and in distribution.

### Convergence in probability

We see that only values that $X_n$ has is $0$ and $n$. So the only candidate to a limit in probability is a random variable $X=0$.  So $P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)=P(X_n>\varepsilon)=1-\frac1n \rightarrow1 \neq0$. So $X_n$ doesn't converge to any random variable in probability.

### Convergence in distribution

The cumulative distribution function of $X_n$ 
is expressed by the pattern : $$
F_{X_n}(t)=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{for} \;t\;\in(-\infty,0) \\
\frac1n&\text{for} \;t\;\in[0,n)\\
1&\text{for}\;t\;\in[n,+\infty)
\end{cases}
$$

And now we see that if in infinity($n \rightarrow \infty$) $F_{X_n}$  will not be a cumulative distribution function  ($\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n} \neq1)$so it cannot converge to any random variable $X$ in distribution.

Can you please verify my proof ?